# Mysql and special chars on keys

Tags: mysql, primary-key, collation

In mysql with "latin1_swedish_ci" collation these records:

```
   INSERT INTO test VALUES ('è');
   INSERT INTO test VALUES ('e');
```

are the same... If this varchar colum is a primary index and I try to inser these values I get a duplicate primary key error. Is it possibile to change this behaviour?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MySQL are you using? It could be a unicode problem

[MySQL VARCHAR Lengths and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997540/mysql-varchar-lengths-and-utf-8)

Comment: on the other hand it might be your character_set_client http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260386/change-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you can insert ascii code to db as the following

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('232');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('101');
```

Then you can read them and  in php use chr function to get character.